# Error logging in with IdentityServer4 and Docker Compose

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker-compose, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to containerize a Blazor Webassembly app with IdentityServer4 and MSSQL using Docker Compose, but I am encountering the following error when logging in:
[image: error logging in]

From what I can tell, the `openid-configuration` looks correct, with the expected authorities and client IDs, as does the resulting `token`.

Interestingly, when hitting the `Register` button, the logged in user is displayed as expected:
[image: register link]

I understand this is a frequently asked question, so here are the things I've confirmed:

- Multiple tabs aren't open
- App is secured by HTTPS
- Works fine when using MSSQL LocalDB - appears to be specific to running in via Docker

Docker Compose integration as it stands can be viewed here: https://github.com/ryanachten/afterimage/compare/feature/add-container-deployment?expand=1

Any idea where I might be going wrong here?

Comment: I generally try to avoid all mentions of `localhost` when using Docker containers. Docker containers are effectively their own little Linux VMs, so `localhost` is equivalent to a container referring to itself and doesn't work for inter-container communications.

Comment: Have you read through [Adding more API Endpoints](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html) yet? If your app and ID4 running side-by-side in the same web project there are extra steps you need to perform, such as including `IdentityServerApi` in your scopes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for your response, I have seen that issue noted elsewhere. I'm not 100% sure how to implement what you're suggesting - the ID4 integration is simply what's outputted by the VS Blazor Webassembly template, so it looks a bit different to the side-by-side integration from what I can tell.

ID4 is registered in the same project as my API. I have tried changing the references to localhost via `builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(x => x.IssuerUri = "https://afterimage.server")`, but this causes retrieving `openid-configuration` to fail.

Comment: I have also read that guide you lined - because of the setup differences, I'm again not really sure how to go about this. Based on the guidelines, I tried registering the identity config in memory like so to no avail: https://gist.github.com/ryanachten/e3752ed7b0a01a9a5d3e2f383ce36818#file-id4-cs